# Can't load saved gensim word2vec model

Tags: python, gensim

I tried saving a word2vec model that I had trained with gensim like so:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
model = Word2Vec(sentences, parameters)
model.save('modelfile.model')
```

Now when I try `Word2Vec.load('modelfile.model')`, I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

Can post the full traceback if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's odd. Are you using the exact same Python environment & gensim version for the `load()` as the `save()`? How did you install gensim & numpy?

When I search for that error, I find other discussions that suggest it may be a symptom of having pickled (saved) a numpy array from numpy 1.16. but trying to unpickle (load) it in an earlier numpy. See for example:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12825#issuecomment-456561919

It looks like numpy has recently merged a fix – https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12837 – but in the meantime your best bet might be making sure the place where you're loading is using numpy 1.16.0+.

Answer (score 0):

I would try `virtualenv` just to avoid any conflicts among packages and environments. `Virtualenv` is a tool to create isolated Python environments. Here are the quick steps to setup `virtualenv` and give it a try to load your `word2vec` model.

```
sudo pip install virtualenv # install virtualenv
virtualenv test1 # create an env named test1
cd test1 # go ot test1
source bin/activate # activate test1
pip install gensim # install your packages for test1 env
python path-to-your-file.py # run your program
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the .model while saving the model, just put "model", as it will be saved in a .bin format

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).